# Is "Happy born day" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I have seen some people writing:

> I wish you a happy born day/date.

And I felt it is wrong but wanted to cross check.

Comment: And on what occasion is that used? Where have you seen it? Are those places specific to a particular dialect of English (like American English, Indian English or Singaporean English or whatever)?

Comment: I saw it on Facebook. The place is Africa and the people who posted it use British English though not as their first language.

Comment: It's probably a joke then. It means the same thing, but it's not an idiom and it sounds strange.

Comment: A friend from Namibia just congratulated me with that expression: «happy bornday»

Comment: I've never come across the phrase in all my born days.

Comment: Is there any grammar mistake in the compound *born day*? What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an emerging alternative phrase for birthday.

The more widely recognized expression is *happy birthday.*

Several references to the term found via Google search suggest it is common among "Black people", apparently African-Americans or in the hip-hop subculture.

See, for example:

https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=born+day&oq=born+day&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j0l2j69i60j69i61.17679j0j4&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espv=1&ie=UTF-8#facrc=_

http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/happy-born-day

Comment: Google is your friend [Happy Born Day!](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Born%20day) and [New ways to say Happy Birthday](http://ask.metafilter.com/208257/New-ways-to-say-Happy-Birthday). This is the first time for me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  If you answered that with more details, it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Centaurus it's not my answer. It's a comment with links which I freely offered to Jim Reynolds.

Comment: @Mari-LouA (et. al.) Maybe it's a new PC way to distinguish those brought into the world by Caesarian section.

Comment: I actually *knew* I should have checked it. This realization passed through me with a damp chill of muted terror even as I clicked to submit the first answer!

Comment: *Loud snortings are heard from Italy* :)

Answer (score 0):

"Bornday" is a term commonly use in West Africa, especially Nigeria. Even though it's not an accepted English phrase, it's accepted in pidgin English.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of colloquial/slang. It's not recognised in English.

Comment: According to who?

Comment: Hi @Gloria, welcome to ELU. On this site we prefer answers to provide some sort of reference if possible, to back up assertions.